# If my engine has a bad pushrod will let knock when it’s idling

Tags: engine

If I have bad pushrod will my engine knock while idling

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If you have a bad push rod, it's going to make noise all the time, not just while idling. A bad push rod (usually this mean it's bent) will make noise no matter what. If the noise doesn't continue at higher RPM, this might indicate a bad lifter or poor oil pressure at idle. If you provide more information about your vehicle, such as year/make/model/engine, we could probably help you much better.

Comment: Why do you think the noise is caused by a pushrod?

Comment: Do you have a known bad pushrod?  If so, remove it from the engine and replace it.  I personally wouldn't assemble an engine with a known bad component.  Or... do you have a noise emanating from the engine at idle and wonder if you have a bad pushrod?  The answer to your question as asked is Yes.  However, many other things will cause an engine to knock at idle too.

Comment: Does your engine have pushrods ?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but there can be many reasons an engine could knock, such as fuel quality, timing, or other mechanical problems.   Can you provide any more details of your situation if you would like more details?

Comment: In addition to this please tell us if you notice knocking when travelling in a straight line, when turning the vehicle and if this noise happens if the car is going fast or slow. It will help to deduce the cause.